# What are the possibilities with sending a Notification in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter

i want to know what the possibilities are with sending a Notification.
Is it possible to send a `NSUserDefaults`?

I know you can send another `viewcontroller`.

Like this:

`NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` is just a notification that is sent out when the defaults are changed. To listen out for it you need this code :

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(defaultsChanged:)  
               name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
             object:nil];
```

This will call the method `defaultsChanged:` when the notification is fired. You need to implement this method like this :

```
- (void)defaultsChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
 // Get the user defaults
NSUserDefaults *defaults = (NSUserDefaults *)[notification object];

// Do something with it
NSLog(@"%@", [defaults objectForKey:@"nameOfThingIAmInterestedIn"]);
}
```

Comment: what is your question? **Is it possible to send a NSUserDefaults?** does it makes sense?

Comment: My question is if it is possible to send other things from a server than NSUserDefaults(wich i just found out) and viewcontrollers

Comment: So, where are you posting the notification?

Comment: I just want to know what the possibilities are what you send to a mobile device with iOs from a server.. If there are more than the 2 possibilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

Here is a possibility of sending a dictionary through `NSNotificationCenter` using

```
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

In the class where you are posting it:

```
NSDictionary *dict;

dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: yourStuff, nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@”someString” object:nil userInfo:dict];
```

In the class doing the listening:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter deHaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someMethod: ) name:@”someString” object:nil];
…
- (void)someMethod:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSDictionary *tmp = notification.userInfo;
//You could access notification.object here too
}
```

**EDIT:**
But usually while receiving Push Notifications from server you have a method called:

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{
for (id key in userInfo) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
    }
}
```

In this method you can get the payload as a `Dictionary` as well

Comment: So, correct me if i'm wrong but..

I can change the "yourStuff" from the server.
I can set the stuff i want to send to different mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

you can't send `NSUserDefault`, but you can send entire Class (Archiver/Unarchiver) data converted in base64 for example. And next create your `NSUserDefault` from `NSData`.

I wrote an article to exchange data using `base64` with applications and use it.

http://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/2012/04/objective-c-share-classes-objects-apps/

hope this helps.